# Angular App only allows dependencies in the constructor to use @Inject

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a newly created Angular app, and am not sure what changed within the app to start behaving like this, but for some reason, every constructor within my app that has dependency parameters included, Angular is requiring me to use `@Inject(dependency)` in my components. I was not needing to do this before, and a lot of the examples I'm seeing don't require this handling of dependencies. Is there something I may have altered that would cause this behavior? Below is an example of one of my components.

*Edit* - I'm currently using Angular 6.0.8

*Edit* - I also forgot, when I don't use the `@Inject` within the constructor's parameters I get this error:
`Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?).`

````
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../_services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [AlertService, AuthenticationService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(
      @Inject(FormBuilder) private formBuilder,
      @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private route,
      @Inject(Router) private router,
      @Inject(AuthenticationService) private authenticationService,
      @Inject(AlertService) private alertService) { }
//This works ^^

  constructor(
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
      private alertService: AlertService) { }
//This does not work
//And yes, I have only one constructor in my code, just showing what worked and what did not.

  ngOnInit() {
      //do some stuff
  }


  onSubmit() {
      //do some more stuff
  }
}```
````

Comment: Did you inject these services to your app.module ?

Comment: I did import them at the top - ex: `import { service } from '../directory/service` Is there somewhere else I need to put them? `NgModule` imports, providers?

Comment: Do you have `RouterModule` in your `exports` in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @Woohoojin I do not, I can try this, but may I ask why I would need to do this?

Comment: @Woohoojin - that does not appear to have fixed the issue :(

Comment: Can you please post your tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you didnt declared these services in your `NgModule` 's providers array. In general, all service have to be defined in a module which it's components will use them as their dependecies, this give them application's scope. Also, declare service in the `providers` will make them a singleton thank to [Angular Dependecy Injector](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) :

There is two way to inject those service to your `module`

```
@NgModule({
 providers: [ ...YourServices]
})
```

Or in your service.ts file, add `@Injectable()` class decorator:

```
// Declare that this service should be created
// by the root application injector.
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
```